# Locating collocated "and" and "four" ("and four")

Tags: etymology, paired-word-requests

Pretext: The etymology of the number word *four* is difficult. The development of Proto-Indo-European *kʷetwor- → Proto-Germanic **feđwōr* > Old English *feower*, Old Saxon *fi(u)war, fior*, Old Norse *fjōrir*, Gothic *fidwōr* etc., is irregular, "initial labial probably by lexical analogy with ‘fiveʼ" (Ringe 2006: 103), as per *wheel* we expect a voiced labial fricative, cp. Latin *quattuor* "4", *quod* "what", *-que* , Gothic *-hw* "and".

Others, eg. Pfeifer suggested PIE *kʷ > pre-PG *p > *f, which is typologically not unikely (cp. Welsh *pedwar*, Boetian πέτταρες, Oscan *petora*) but would be uncommon for Germanic. Since there is no good explanation, I file it under /dev/null and arrive at arbitrary conclusions. See also on [linguistics.SE]: [1](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11334), [2](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15674), [3](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28953). Also, there is no good reason that the dental would become lost, whose only evidence within the Germanic branch is Gothic? Latin *quartus* requires a similar explanation, possibly dissimilation from **quatwortos* ([4](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3216))

So my impression was that *f became devoiced by preceding voiceless dental in the cluster *tw somewhere on the way to *đ < *t under Verner's law. And then *the front fell off* (Clarke and Dawe). A similar development is assumed with *quirky* < PIE **terkw-*.  This is barely compatible with the Gothic situation where d and đ are not distinguished in writing ‹d› (Hempel: § 33) while unvoiced th under Grimm's law does occasionally correspond to f ([5](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3798)). Which is to imply that **kʷe(t)* was free to undergo rebracketing at least in North-West Germanic and perhaps earlier.

From **penkʷe* "five" I remember the hypothesis that *-kʷe "and" was involved in its formation, though I can't recall who wrote that, or what the argument was—in hindsight I am likely under a misapprehension (PS: Blažek, *Numerals*, sumarizes several hypotheses). Hence I was wondering.

Question: Does any quotable, lexical evidence of "and four" exist?

In particular, I am *imagining* that the count "a one, a two …" would continue *... a three **and** four*. So if anyone could dispell this illusion for me, that would be great. Although I don't know how you'd rule that out, since it is not part of the written register and awful to search (I do remember a question about the count).

It would be even better if a constructive answer shows corroborating evidence. For example, the half steps of four by four rhythm in German are phrased as "und". Since *and* is not cognate to *-hw*, it would be a case of lexical replacement at best.

So this is an etymological `paired-word-request` rather than an `etymology`.

Disclaimer: Yes this is silly, lateral thinking very much required. I cannot stress enough that this is a real question. **kʷetwor-* is not attested in Anatolian, the branch that is likely the earliest to split off from Indo-Euopean. Implying, internal derivation must obtain if **kʷetwor-* was innovated in core Indo-European. However, that's not necessarily due to *-kʷe "and".

Comment: I don't know of any, and I think the rhythmic aspect might make the preservation of "and four" less likely. Musicians sometimes "count in" the beginning of a song as "a one, a two, a one two three four", where the initial one and two come on the first and third beats. While I recall children's chants beginning "one, two, three, four", I can't think of any with "one, two, three and four".